# Azure Cloud Services Classic - "Deployment could not be created"

Tags: azure-cloud-services, azure-deployment-slots

We have a Cloud Service that we have been deploying/updating without issue. In the past two weeks every time we try to deploy the package we are getting the error "Deployment could not be created - There was an error processing your request. Try again in a few moments".

I am at a loss as to how to even debug the issue to get more detail. if anybody has any advice on how to get a better error description would be appreciated.

The only changes in this deployment are some changes to the static files in the package so it is unclear what is causing the issue. The process we use is (1) build the package, (2) upload the package, (3) deploy in the staging environment. The package gets uploaded but fails to deploy (step 3).

Any help as to what the issue is or how to get better diagnostic information woudl be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that when an instance gets deployed that cloud service gets pinned to a cluster. If the cluster runs out of space then no further deployments can be made.

This is independent to how much space an individual subscription has as a cluster appears to be used by multiple subscriptions.

I had to create a new cloud service (getting new IP address etc) and deloy to that. I assume this then moved that whole service to a totally new cluster.

The two links below share more information.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-allocation-failures

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-troubleshoot-constrained-allocation-failed

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there may be a problem with the platform or deployment procedure used by the cloud service provider.

You can check the deployment logs if there are any error messages or warnings that might provide more information about the issue. and use diagnose and solve problem to more information

[image]

Try to use an alternative way or tool to deploy the package, This can support to determining whether the problem is unique to the deployment procedure I created a Cloud service (classic) like below:

[image]

Make sure the packages of service configuration allowable format of [service configuration file.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-model-and-package) The service configuration file is not packaged with the application, but is uploaded to Azure as a separate file and is used to configure the cloud service You don't need to re-deploy your cloud service if you upload a new service configuration file. Once the cloud service is in use, the configuration parameters can be altered.

[image]

***Reference***:

[Create and deploy a cloud service (classic) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-how-to-create-deploy-portal)

Comment: Thanks for your help but the problem turned out to be that the cluster the service was deployed on had no more space allocated. I have placed a answer to the question.